# Arduino uno and 1602A I2C not working

Tags: display

I'm a newbie in engineering.

I bought this with arduino learning kit.

It's simply not working.

There are several possible problems:

- The display is not working due to a hardware problem. It could need to be repaired or soldered better.
- The library that I chose could be buggy (software problem)

How can I check this? Thanks!

PS Build-in led is blinking as expected.

Here is the code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

void setup()
{
  lcd.init();
  lcd.begin(8,2);

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}


void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("TEST");
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("   ");
  delay(1000);
}
```

[image][image]

Comment: Do you have pull up resistors from sda and scl to your vdd?

Comment: Did you run scanner program first to verify the address of the I2C? you'll find the software at the bottom of this page https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/LCD-Blue-I2C

Comment: Scanner is definitely best approach, but if 0x27 address is wrong, try 0x35 as a quick test. Unless you have soldered jumpers, these are the two most likely addresses. Your wiring looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this address 0x3F or 0x27

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE); // or 0x27
void setup() {
lcd.begin(16, 2);
}
void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("TEST");
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("   ");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Scaner helped me to find this address. https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/LCD-Blue-I2C